# Wildcard selector working weird

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this selector

```
[id^="subf"] {}
```

which will select all elements whose ID starts with subf, okay?
But now I want to select only the immediate PARENT DIVs inside these DIVs like this:

```
<div id="subf1">
 <div></div>  <-- this DIV but not the child DIVs inside
 <div></div>  <-- and this DIV but not the child DIVs inside
</div>
```

So I use this:

```
[id^="subf"] > div {}
```

or this:

```
[id^="subf"] > div, [id^="subf"] > div + div {}
```

but none of them are working fine because this: [id^="subf"] > div seems to affect the parent "subf1" DIV as well and I dont want that. What is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it work for your situation to just use `[id^="subf"] div {} and then [id^="subf"] div div {} to undo anything you want undone? What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: that would imply double the code. I want to set position absolute to the child DIVs but not for the one with the subf ID.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Can you provide an example?

Comment: My example is already in the question.

Comment: There's no way that selector could possibly affect the parent div assuming its own parent doesn't also match the attribute selector. Something is missing. Maybe show us the style declarations along with the selector.

Comment: This selector `[id^="subf"] > div ` doesn't work the way you claim it to work.. for clarity use the same selector in Jquery in your console window and check the results

Comment: I am monitoring it on firebug and thats what I get. [id^="subf"] > div is affecting subf1 as well.

Comment: @CainNuke, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kxnhyg5f/  [it looks fine for me] and create a fiddle with generating your problem (for full understanding), it will help us solve your problem

Comment: @CainNuke is your `#subf1` element contained inside another element with an `id` beginning with "subf"?

Comment: No, James, it doesnt. Mahedi, I checked your fiddle and it works fine here but I dont understand why my example wont work on my page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `[id^="subf"] > div` appears to be working fine.

Here's an example where only the immediate children of `[id^="subf"]` have a yellow `background-color` and a `border-radius` applied:

```css
[id^="subf"] {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 6px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

[id^="subf"] div {
display: block;
float: left;
width: calc(50% - 12px);
height: calc(50% - 12px);
margin: 6px;
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

[id^="subf"] > div {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="subf1">

<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>  <!-- this DIV but not the child DIVs inside -->

<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>  <!-- and this DIV but not the child DIVs inside -->

</div>

<div id="subf2">

<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>  <!-- this DIV but not the child DIVs inside -->

<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>  <!-- and this DIV but not the child DIVs inside -->

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, on your example it works fine thats why I dont understand why it wont on mine.